# How do I make Organization chart in Web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-part

We are trying to create Organizational chart with pictures,title and Dept. Data from the list. But they need that Data from Active Directory. We are in SP 2010 Environment. I am hoping that some has jQuery code for the Web part.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the list to store the user data and create organization chart by JQuery.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

Organization/Hierarchy Chart on SharePoint (using jquery, Javascipt-CSOM).

https://abinjaik.com/2013/08/14/organizationhierarchy-chart-on-sharepoint-using-jquery-javascipt-csom/

More reference:

Free SharePoint Organizational Chart WebPart SimpleChart for SharePoint.

http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/free-sharepoint-organizational-chart-webpart-simplechart-for-sharepoint/